# Conditional Query Based on DB Status

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, recovery, mirroring

What would the syntax of a conditional query that depends on the db status be? Basically, the equivalent of this pseudo-code?

```
IF [My database is in RECOVERY mode]
    [DO SOME STUFF]
ELSE
    [DO SOME OTHER STUFF]
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>IF DATABASEPROPERTY('DBName','IsInRecovery') = 1</strike>

Edit: Although that is deprecated use

```
IF DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DBName','Status')='RECOVERING'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying the first option has been deprecated and the second is the preferred method?

Comment: @Ocelot20 - Yes. `DATABASEPROPERTYEX` is the one to use.